# Why Python does not see newly built CV2 package in Windows 10 PC?

Tags: python, opencv, cmake

I am following step by step instructions from "[How to Build and Install OpenCV from Source](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_fqpYLM6SCw)". I was able to get everything installed and compiled properly in Visual studio.

When I built "INSTALL" project, it was completed as follows with no issues. 
[image: INSTALL build at Visual Studio 2019]

I added the path "C:\object_detector\opencv-4.3.0\build\install\x64\vc16\bin" to Environment settings.

CMAKE Python path is the same version I am running when testing the CV2. When I issue "import cv2" at Python prompt, I get error : "No module name cv2"

When I run opencv_version.exe in the new build folder shows exact OpenCV version I built. This suggests the built was successful.

Why Python does not see my build ?

[image: No module name cv2]

Comment: Did you uninstall the previous version of OpenCV installed thru pip? This is suppose to be the first step even before following any step from the video.

Comment: Yes there is no cv2.

Answer (score 0):

The issues was that during make, it did not update Include folder in system path. Once added, it was fine.